# Why I get only the last id props after this for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I'm probably wrong on how `JavaSript` assign the properties in a `for loop`, how can I fix this problem?

```
var setImageSize = function (i) {

    instances[i].img = $('<img id="jquery-background-zoom-'+i+'"/>');
    var img = instances[i].img;
    img.hide();
    img.bind('load', function(e) {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace('jquery-background-zoom-', ''));
        instances[id].settings.bg.width = parseInt($(this).width());
        instances[id].settings.bg.height = parseInt($(this).height());

        $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '[' + i + ' ' + instances[id].settings.bg.width + ', ' + instances[id].settings.bg.height + ']<br>');
        updateDefaultValues(instances[id]);

        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('body').append(img);
    img.attr('src', instances[i].settings.bg.url);
}

var setEvent = function (i) {
    return function (e) {
        var inst = instances[$(this).index()];
        $('#debug').html(i + ' ' + inst.settings.bg.url);
        $(this).bind('mousemove', {i:instances[$(this).index()]}, setFollowMouse);
    }
}

var init = function (options) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this_obj.length; i ++) {

        instances.push ({id:i, element:this_obj.get(i), settings:$.extend(true, defaults, options)});
        instances[i].settings.bg.url = $(this_obj.get(i)).css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/'/g, '').replace(/"/g, '');

        $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '<br>' + i + ' -- ' + instances[i].toSource() + '<br><br>');

        setImageSize (i);

        $(instances[i].element).hover(setEvent(i), function () {
            $(this).unbind('mousemove', setFollowMouse);
            zoomOut($(this).index());
        });
    }
}

init(); // at the bottom of jQuery plug-in
```

in the `first test` I get what I expect:

```
({id:0, settings:{url:"http://localhost/js/img/example_0.jpg", other_propos:'relative to the id 0'}})
({id:1, settings:{url:"http://localhost/js/img/example_1.jpg", other_propos:'relative to the id 1'}})
({id:2, settings:{url:"http://localhost/js/img/example_2.jpg", other_propos:'relative to the id 2'}})
```

in the `event test`, when I invoke the `mousemove` event, i get only the `last element propos` but the right `id`, why?

```
({id:0, settings:{url:"http://localhost/js/img/example_2.jpg", other_propos:'relative to the id 2'}})
({id:1, settings:{url:"http://localhost/js/img/example_2.jpg", other_propos:'relative to the id 2'}})
({id:2, settings:{url:"http://localhost/js/img/example_2.jpg", other_propos:'relative to the id 2'}})
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, how can I avoid this?

I suspect the problem could be in `setImageSize` method, which loads the `img` element `background image`, needed to save it's real `width` and `height`.

Could it be in the load delay?

I'm not sure because the tests talks about a wrong props assign in the for loop.

here is http://jsfiddle.net/tonino/CFPTa/ I'm sure the problem is in the jquery load event, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I don't think `$(this).index()` is doing what you think it's doing.  Just replace that call with `i`

Comment: You are showing something else. For example you have ` element:this_obj.get(i)` which is not shown in `first test`.  `'mousemove', {i:instances` typo? Could move your example to http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: `$(this).index()` returns the current index of an element, if it is the first is 0, if the second 1 and so on. This should work like the array `instances`, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what's going on then sorry, it looks right to me...

Comment: I've baked a http://jsfiddle.net/tonino/CFPTa/ of the plug-in, I think the problem is at the method `prepareImageSize` because it calls asynchronous `load` event for every image, and then I get the error. You can see the `plug-in works correctly` only with the `last image`, the first and the second are treated as the last one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with what you've written stems from the closure effect.

Inside your anonymous hover function you're referring to the `i` variable, but that event isn't getting called until all of the iterations are through. When you refer to the `i` variabe inside the anonymous function it doesn't take a copy of `i` as it is at that time - it simply uses a reference to it. This means that when you increment the `i` variable you're also incrementing the one that the anonymous function refers to, so after all three iterations all three of the anonymous functions you've made refer to the same `i` value: 2.

I believe that making a method factory method will work, as follows:

```
var factory = function(i) {
    return function (e) {

        var inst = instances[$(this).index()];
        // event test, here I get only the last instance propos but the right id, why??
        $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '<br>' + inst.toSource() + '<br>');

        $(this).bind('mousemove', {i:instances[$(this).index()]}, setFollowMouse); // e.data.id
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < this_obj.length; i ++) {
    instances.push ({id:i, element:this_obj.get(i), settings:$.extend(true, defaults, options)});
    instances[i].settings.bg.url = $(this_obj.get(i)).css('background-image').replace('url(', '').replace(')', '').replace(/'/g, '').replace(/"/g, '');

    // first test
    $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '<br>' + instances.toSource() + '<br>');

    $(instances[i].element).hover(factory(i), function () {
        $(this).unbind('mousemove', setFollowMouse);
        zoomOut($(this).index());
    });
}
```

When the factory method is called, the returned function will capture the scope of the factory function at the time it was called - meaning that the `i` variable now does not change.

See this post for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff696765

Comment: I believe this is the problem, as well, but Jeff's fixed code doesn't pass any arguments to `factory()` in the fourth-to-last line; shouldn't it be passing `i` there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've changed the code with this approach but unfortunately this haven't solved my problem.

Comment: this is the same thing I've done for years on `ActionScript3` to pass variables to events.

Comment: I've just added another portion of code I initially thought it was useless.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with closure. Functions aren't run until the loop is completed. You can fix this using immediately invoked functions.

```
// will awlays output 5

    for (var i = 0, len = 5; i < len; i += 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log(i);
        }, 100);   
    }

    // this is correct
    for (i = 0, len = 5; i < len; i += 1) {
        (function (i) { // notice the immediately invoked function
            setTimeout(function () {
              console.log(i);
            }, 100);   
        }(i));
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LBahU/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure on how I could apply this syntax in my code, can you write an example?

Comment: @vitto This answer is similar to what was in my answer, but inlined instead of having the method factory method in a var. So to do it in your case you'd just go `.hover(function(i){return function(e){...}}(i)`

Comment: thankyou @Jeff, I'll try, but if you say this is the same thing I suspect I'm missing something else.